# Js autoload function is not working on flexigrid

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud, flexigrid

Well... I am using flexigrid and grocery crud and i am trying to autoload table with js function. I have followed these steps to do this but it isn't working. Table should auto refresh each 5 seconds when something new is added. What am i doing wrong?

**js file contain**

```
var interval = null;

window.onload = function() {
    interval = setInterval(callFunc, 5000);    
};

function callFunc() {
       $("#ajax_refresh_and_loading").trigger("click");
}
```

**js calling on controller**

```
$jsfile = base_url('index.php/assets/bootstrap/js/refresh.js');
        $crud->set_js($jsfile);
```

**Steps i have followed**

[Mini tutorial](https://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/2250-flexigrid-autorefresh/)

Comment: check the console for errors

Comment: thank you very much!! it was a stupid thing, i haven't check the console... i will put the right route. Also, note that base_url() is useless thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the route and deleted base_url() because it was useless.

```
$jsfile = 'assets/bootstrap/js/refresh.js';

        $crud->set_js($jsfile);
```